# Map a normal image to a cubemap

Tags: c++, graphics, directx11

How can I map a normal non T form image to a cube map?

and if there is no manner with which to do this, is it possible to, via DX11, split the image, as the image may be generated on the fly?

Cheers.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You could chop an image up into 6 parts and put it into a cube map but that doesn't do anything so I don't think that answers your question :p

Comment: I will generate an image in the program itself using interpolation techniques and then map the image onto a cubemap. The image generation is a constant thing depending on movement.

Comment: If there was a way to do split the image in run time I'm open to suggestions on how to implement such a technique. the image generation will have been finished at that stage and the mapping is all that's left.

Comment: A cube map, when used as a skybox, is a seamless panorama. Is your question that you want to take an image that's not a panorama and make it into a panorama?

Comment: I have a set of spherical panoramic images similar to something like this [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Nyk%C3%B6ping_-_Panorama_-_10_-_P1290273.jpg) and I am going to interpolate an image between 2 particular images then map this image to a cubemap. The first step is trying to map something like that to a cubemap without the use of auxiliary programs to change the image format i.e. dividing it into 6 different files or changing it to become a T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a spherical panoramic photo it isn't too difficult luckily (:

Basically what you need to do is make a sphere, texture it with your picture, then render 6 times from the center of the sphere, once with the camera facing each of the directions of the cube.

You just need to make sure and give the camera a 90 degree field of view when rendering each face of the cube, and the resolution needs to be square (such as 1000x1000)

BTW you can use this technique with any 3d rendered scene to make a cubemap of it.  You aren't limited to a spherical panorama photo on a sphere, you can render whatever geometry you want.

People often use this sort of technique for baking out reflection data, or for doing light probes and things like that.  I have heard they also interpolate between samples sometimes, so maybe you are doing something similar :p

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a light field viewer. I have a grid of around 100 pre-rendered images of a 3D rendered scene using a path tracer. I just want to map 1 image (which is interpolated on the fly from these images) and then put it on a cube map, or a sphere if that can work so I can look around the image. For the moment I just want to get a cubemap with one of my images (or a sphere with it on the inside).

Comment: Either a sphere or a cube would work.  If you want help on texture mapping a spherical panoramic image onto a sphere you should probably ask a new question specifically about that so that more people will give answers.  If you are looking for info on how to interpolate on the grid of images, I'd say per pixel trilinear interpolation would be a good start.  If you want better quality you can do cubic spline interpolation (etc) but trilinear is fast and is likely what would be used at runtime when doing real time graphics. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation

Comment: I'll do another post about texture mapping an image onto a sphere then, thank you for your informative answers!